# FreeBSD CARP doesn't work in VirtualBox with bridged adapter

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, freebsd, carp

I have two identical VirtualBox machines running FreeBSD. Their networking is set up using "Bridged Adapter" option. I've followed [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/carp.html) instructions step-to-step, but I still not able to access CARP'ed IP from host system.

What's wrong and how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with "Promiscuous Mode" setting of the bridged virtual network adapter. For CARP'ed IP to be accessible from host system, it should be set to "Allow all" for both Virtual Machines.

Setting that fixes the problem.